# Jupyter Notebook no longer automatically opens in browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

When I go to run jupyter notebooks via terminal... calling

`jupyter notebook`

I see:

```
[I 15:33:26.341 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/ellenarena/opt/anaconda3/envs/ellenDL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 15:33:26.341 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/ellenarena/opt/anaconda3/envs/ellenDL/share/jupyter/lab
[I 15:33:26.344 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/ellenarena
[I 15:33:26.344 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:33:26.344 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=2e39eea78241a1f47a1071cad5210ba3531007b7b7f73e0a
[I 15:33:26.344 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2e39eea78241a1f47a1071cad5210ba3531007b7b7f73e0a
[I 15:33:26.344 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 15:33:26.356 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/ellenarena/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-24533-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=2e39eea78241a1f47a1071cad5210ba3531007b7b7f73e0a
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=2e39eea78241a1f47a1071cad5210ba3531007b7b7f73e0a
5:15: syntax error: A “"” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)
```

However, no browser window automatically opens... I have to copy/paste the URL.  The notebooks work/run... but this is a bit of a pain having to stop and copy/paste to open things.

It's not a problem with my browser - was working fine before.  I did do a recent fresh install of Anaconda and the location of anaconda3/ folder has moved... could that be a reason why?

Also in case it's need - here is the version of Jupyter I'm running:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.2
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.2
jupyter lab      : 2.0.1
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Running on a Mac 10.14.6 with Python 3.8.2 and conda 4.8.3.

Comment: Is the line _5:15: syntax error: A “"” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)_ part of the related output?

Comment: This issue has been resolved.  It now automatically opens in the browser from the command line.